# SQL call in browser different from SQL call in MySQL Workbench

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, localhost, mysql-workbench

I'm making a web app with a function to let a user checkout a book from a library database if they meet requirements (no overdue books, the book is available, etc.).

**The Problem**

When getBook.php is invoked by the JS, it connects to my DB and sends a pretty basic query: 'get the title of a book with this ID'. When called in MySQL Workbench, it returns the appropriate title. However, when called from the browser's JS function, the query returns an empty result.

**What I've Tried**

For simplicity's sake, I eliminated all of the fancy error-checking and jquery creation stuff and just had my JS repeat back to me what it got from the php for now.

I also looked at Stackoverflow's [SyntaxError: missing ] after element list when try to pass object parameter to onclick function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314837/syntaxerror-missing-after-element-list-when-try-to-pass-object-parameter-to-o) question, but that didn't help either.

I peppered getBook.php with die() functions, but every die function I used just confirmed that the script works like I want it to except for one thing: when I use that sql statement in MySQL Workshop, I get the title of the book I want as a result. When getBook.php is called from the browser, it gets the following:

> {"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}

**Relevant JavaScript**

```
function checkout(isbnNo=1, userID=1) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/checkout.php",
    dataType: "text",
    // @TODO: add scanner functionality to populate isbn,
    //  add functionality to populate user
    data:
    {
        isbn: isbnNo,
        user: userID
    },
    success: function(result) {
        // change #button-text to house result (for now)
        // @TODO: delete errorcheck when done
        $('#button-text').html(result);
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(status + ' ||| ' + error);
    }
});
}

// extraneous functions...

// THIS FUNCTION RIGHT HERE. VVVVVVVVV
function getBook(bookID=1, userNo=1) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/getBook.php",
        data: {
            book: bookID,
            user: userNo
        },
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(result) {

            $("#button-text").html(result);
            console.log(result);
        }
    })
}
```

**getBook.php**

```
<?php
require("utility.php");
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
    $book = (int)cleanInput($_POST["book"]); // from string to int
    logIntoDataBase($dbconn, "../docs/server-info-sr.txt");
    $query = "  SELECT
                    title
                FROM
                    books
                WHERE
                    isbn = $book;";
    $result = $dbconn->query($query);
    if ($result)
        echo json_encode($result);
    else
        echo "ERROR: unsuccessful query";
    //disconnect when finished
    disconnectDB($dbconn,$dbName);
}
?>
```

*(cleanInput(), for anyone who's curious)*

```
function cleanInput($data) { 
    $data = trim($data); 
    $data = stripslashes($data); 
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    $data = htmlentities($data);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Use your browser console to see what your Ajax is sending and receiving. If checkout.php is being called, then you can insert breakpoints (die commands) to see where it’s breaking.  Your console should be able to even show you the line causing a problem. No need to guess.

Comment: FYI — Also, your sql query is open to injection. Check out prepared statements.

Comment: @TimMorton Thank you for the comment about prepared statements holy crap xD

Unfortunately, after exploring my PHP function with die() statements as suggested, everything seems to be operating like it should. The only problem is that, when my SQL statement is executed through the browser, the returned result is:

{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}

while in MySQL Workbench it's "test book 1", as it should be.

Comment: It appears that you have proven your AJAX is working.  It's just not getting good data to hand back to the browser.  You've also established that the sql query itself is good.  That leaves your database abstraction.  Without seeing your `$dbconn` object, I don't know how it's supposed to work; but it does seem to be missing a part.  Typically, `$result` would be an object that enables you to traverse the result set via something like a `fetch()` method.  All those null variables could be because it hasn't fetched a row yet...

Comment: Example of one way to do it with PDO: `$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table');
 
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['field1'].' '.$row['field2']; //etc...
}` This illustrates that you need to iterate through the result set.  Your database abstraction is likely very similar to this.

Comment: @TimMorton fetching the row after I got the query fixed it, yep. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I was able to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer credit goes to @TimMorton Tim Morton for gently reminding me that I need to use fetch_assoc to fetch a row from my returned queries in PHP:

```
$query = "  SELECT
                b.title, b.isbn
            FROM
                books b
            WHERE
                b.isbn = $book;";
$myArray = array();
$result = $dbconn->query($query);
if ($result) {
    // vvvvv the while loop with the fetch_assoc fixed everything
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $myArray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($myArray[0]);
}
```

Comment: And this query is still very vulnerable :( Why don't you even put quotes around `$book`?