# Pass the value of a local variable to the dragstart handler in the dynamic creation of an input element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've already read a number of similar question but could not find any that answer to mine.

I have the following loop

```
$.each(data.modules, function(i, field) {
  let $li = $(`<li><div> Name: ${field.name}</div><div>Description: ${field.description}</div></li>`).appendTo('#moduleList');
  $('<input class="set_inputs" type="button" value="select" ondragstart="dragstart_handler(event)" draggable="true" />').wrap('<div />').parent().appendTo($li);
});
```

My goal is to pass `field` to `dragstart_handler(event, field)` but I do not know how to pass a local variable in the dynamic build of the input element.

I have already tried

```
$('<input class="set_inputs" type="button" value="drag me" ondragstart="dragstart_handler(event, \""+field+"\")" draggable="true" />').data('field', field).wrap('<div />').parent().appendTo($li);
```

but it is not working.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, can you try like this : `$('<input class="set_inputs" type="button" value="drag me" ondragstart="dragstart_handler(event, ' + field + ')" draggable="true" />').data('field', field).wrap('<div />').parent().appendTo($li);` ?

Comment: @Swati: thank you for your help. Your solution gives the following error <SyntaxError: missing ] after element list>. I've found the solution as described in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314837/syntaxerror-missing-after-element-list-when-try-to-pass-object-parameter-to-o) post

```
$.each(data.modules, function(i, field) {
  var $listItem = $(`<li><button type="button" class="set_inputs" draggable="true">`+ field.name +`</button></li>`).appendTo('#moduleList');
  
 $listItem.find('button').on('dragstart', function(event) {
    dragstart_handler(field);
  });
});
```